# git: how can you trace back the history of pull commands having been run?

Tags: git

I would like to trace the time and the commit hash preceding each `pull`, for the last several `pull`s made on a given repo on a given machine. Is this information kept available in any way?

Looks like the file bearing the branch of interest's name (e.g. master)  under `.git/logs/refs/heads/` contains all the information. The time of the pull is provided there as a unix epoch timestamp, which can be easily read by utilities or online websites like http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php.

Perhaps though someone can confirm that, or better yet provide a git command for browsing through pull history.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Roll back the machine to the point prior to the last pull.

Comment: Are you looking for pulls from  the repo (outbound) or to the repo (inbound)?  On inbound since by default pull is short for git fetch  followed by git merge, so if there are no changes upstream on an inbound, I am not sure if anything would get updated.

Comment: @doon pulls to the repo (inbound). Running `git pull`. The case where no changes have been made is of no interest here..

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to use git for something else than what it is intended for, and that may not work well.  Could you elaborate on what you want to do?

Comment: It was meant to manage the linux kernel, so we all do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log -g master` seems to provide that exact information.
It appears to return the time of each `pull` along the new hash it brought in.

`git reflog master` gives a subset of this information.

Comment: I improved on your answer, maybe you would like to edit it for further precision, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

so assuming that You are only interested in when (localtime)  master's head changed, I wonder if the TimeStamp of on the file is good enough.

```
# ls -l .git/refs/heads/master                                                                                                                                             
-rw-r--r--  1 doon  staff  41 Jul 12 12:40 .git/refs/heads/master
```

and git log confirms this

```
 git log --pretty=format:"%ad %H"                                                                                                                                         Tue Jul 12 16:40:04 2016 +0000 814879408b6b61e0583de2ed9e5b1cad09becc05
Tue Jul 12 16:40:03 2016 +0000 4e524ddf0defd07994d0a630debae338895ecd05
```

And it isn't a pull that you are interested in, persea, but more along the lines of last refchange/commit?

(I am currently EDT (-0400) which explains the difference in Timestamps)